# The request failed or the service did not respond in a timely fashion in MS SQL 2012

Tags: sql-server

I have got following error, when tried to start SQL server instance in `SQL Server Configurtion Manager`.

```
The request failed or the service did not respond in a timely fashion.
Consult the event log or other applicable error logs for details.
```

I have researched a lot in this topic, so I have already disabled `TCP/IP` connection and selected `Local system` under `Built-in account` button. These haven't solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to temporary specify some "powered" account (domain or local administrator) for SQL Server service to log on under and then try to start it again. If the test will be successful then your specified built in account have some permission issues.

**Later Edit**

---

Try to type your username\password here (I assume that you are power user on your machine)

[image]

Comment: What should I do exactly?

Comment: `WMI Provider Error`, when I try to login.

Comment: Run as administrator?

Comment: It is started, but after refresh, it is stopped again.

Comment: Check Windows Log then